# SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Service Data Processing Extension Issue

Tags: database, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

My Dev Environment is SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition.
Ref： http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154655%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Following above reference, I defined a data source and put the dll into the bin folder and modified the configure files.

When I deploying the reports, sometime fail sometime success, don't know reason and when...

1. When checking the report from localhost/Reports error shows:
   An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
   An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'ExtReport' that is either not registered for this report server or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services. (rsDataExtensionNotFound)
2. When checking data source, error shows：
   The data processing extension used for this report is not available. It has either been uninstalled, or it is not configured correctly.
3. One error shows in Windows EvenViewer:
   Report Server (MSSQLSERVER) cannot load the ExReport extension.

Any one can help on this? and, how could I diagnostic, I don't know how to check/debug or is there any logs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem trying to create a Data Processing Extension and finally realized that I was building my extension as a .net 4.0 dll, and ssrs only supports 3.5 (uses 2.0.50727 clr)

I couldn't find any logs, didn't see anything in Process Monitor, and finally just attached to the ReportingServicesService from visual studio, which showed what dlls it was loading after restarted the service and attempted to hit the local SSRS webpage. After it didn't even attempt to load my DPE dll and didn't throw any exceptions I could break on, I realized that it was running on the 2.0 clr, which of course can't load 4.0 dlls

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e631f82a-69cc-4e63-af56-159b32f88116/what-version-of-the-clr-does-reporting-services-2012-run-under?forum=sqlreportingservices